# Dose CoreBluetooth work on IOS6.0,IOS6.1,IOS6.1.2?

Tags: core-bluetooth

i am working on bluetooth4.0 , but i found that CoreblueTooth cannot run on iOS 6+,my iphone4s is IOS 6.1.2.

it cannot find any device(i am sure the device is power on), the Log as below every time:

CoreBluetooth[WARNING]  is not powered on

Dose anyone have encounter this issue?

Comment: The warning message is telling you that the Bluetooth radio in the iPhone is not on.  It is not telling you that your peripheral is off. You need to post the code you are using to set up and use Bluetooth.

Comment: mbuc91 has a more detailed answer, but in response to your basic question: yes, Core Bluetooth works on all of those versions of iOS on an iPhone 4S. I've used it to communicate with an accessory on each of those versions. There are odd bugs with particular older iOS 6.0 versions that can result in null UUIDs being returned from peripherals, but the devices themselves are found just fine even there.

Answer (score 3):

The status CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn means not only that Bluetooth is turned on, but also that your instance of CBCentralManager or CBPeripheralManager is ready to use.  You **must** initialize your manager, then wait for its state to change before using it.  For example, if you are acting as a Central, you would initialize it with the following:

```
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

And implement the delegate method `centralManagerDidUpdateState:`

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerPoweredOn)
    {
        //do your stuff, it's ready
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing on a iPhone 4S running 6.0.1. The iPhone is in central role and I don't see your warning.

Can you please be more specific about what you're doing? 
- Are you in peripheral or central role?

Have you initialized the CBCentralManager (if you're a central) as follows?

```
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

I hope I could help you